# Unable to use "unescape()" on strings stored in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have about 7000 lines of text with unicode notations Eg: `7123    \ud83d\ude4c\ud83d\ude4fQue Deus nos defenda das ruindades calmas e dos odios q sorriem \ud83d\ude07\ud83d\udc4a`

When I print the string directly as below I get the symbols as I should,

```
$("#filteredContent").text(unescape("7123   \ud83d\ude4c\ud83d\ude4fQue Deus nos defenda das ruindades calmas e dos odios q sorriem \ud83d\ude07\ud83d\udc4a"));
```

Output: 7123    Que Deus nos defenda das ruindades calmas e dos odios q sorriem

But, if I insert all the strings into an array and try to print them then I cannot see the symbols,

```
        var main = $("#mainContent").text();
        var arr = main.split("\n");
        var index = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                $("#filteredContent").append(unescape(arr[i].trim()));
        }
```

`Output: 7123   \ud83d\ude4c\ud83d\ude4fQue Deus nos defenda das ruindades calmas e dos odios q sorriem \ud83d\ude07\ud83d\udc4a`

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcjydwr7/**

Comment: You can use Ctrl+M when making your post to create working examples of the issue.

Comment: Seems to work for me if I use a string for `main` - http://jsbin.com/huxosuxana/edit?html,js,output So probably the issue is with the `$.text()` call? What does your `mainContent` node actually look like?

Comment: @KarlReid I have added a JSFiddle

Comment: @Taplar I have added a JSFiddle

Comment: This works for me : https://jsfiddle.net/52xwufvt/2/ but I am not confident enough to make it an answer- I just banged some code together using Google, I don't really understand the issues around your question. So I can't  say 'this is the correct answer' with any confidence.

Comment: @KarlReid Its the correct answer you can post it back, I wanted to test it out before commenting anything. Just one small glitch when `arr[i]` has string like `\Black` or `\stuff` the code throws an error

Comment: If it works for you, great, but I will wait for someone with a better understanding of the issues than I have to post an authoritative answer.